# expression must be a pointer to a complete object type when using array with 3 indexes

Tags: arrays, c, encryption

i got a problem with my code, i want to put new sentences in kalimatBaru from the array kalimat. but i got an error "expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" at the encrypt function

```
void encrypt(char *sentence) {
    int panjang = strlen(sentence);
    char kalimatBaru[99][99][99];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        int panjang = strlen(sentence[i]);
        int index = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k+=panjang)
            {
               kalimatBaru[i][j][index] = sentence[i][j][k];
               index++;
            }
        }
        strcpy(sentence, kalimatBaru);
    } 
}

int main() {
    int jumlahKalimat, jumlahKata, kataTerbanyak = 0;
    printf("Masukkan jumlah kalimat: ");
    scanf("%d", &jumlahKalimat);

    char kalimat[jumlahKalimat][99][99];

    for (int i = 0; i < jumlahKalimat; i++) {
        printf("Masukkan jumlah kata kalimat ke-%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &jumlahKata);
        if (jumlahKata > kataTerbanyak) {
            kataTerbanyak = jumlahKata;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < jumlahKata; j++) {
            scanf("%s", kalimat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < jumlahKalimat; i++) {
        printf("Kalimat ke-%d (encrypted): ", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < kataTerbanyak; j++) {
            if (kalimat[i][j][0] != '\0') {
                encrypt(kalimat[i][j][0]);
                printf("%s ", kalimat[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i tried to pass the parameter with three index but it still show no effect

Comment: `sentence` is pointer to char. How can you index it this way `sentence[i][j][k]`? `strlen(sentence[i]);` `strlen` requires `char *` you pass char. You need to read again your book pointer and array chapter. You completely do not understand it

Comment: The statement "encrypt(kalimat[i][j][0]);" implies that you are encrypting one string/word at a time.  Is that the program's intent or is the program supposed to perform some encryption on a sentence containing a fixed number of words?

Comment: The array definition `char kalimatBaru[99][99][99];` allocates almost 1 MiB of memory on the stack.  On Windows, you are likely to find you don't have that much space left; on Unix, you probably have 8 MiB for the stack, but chewing up one eighth of that for the array is a bit dubious.  Consider using dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` and `free()`) — or review whether you need quite so much space if you've not yet learned about dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Your code is incomplete without includes.  Stackoverflow is in English so your non-English variable names limits readability of your audience.  Check return value of I/O operations like scanf() otherwise you may be operating on non-initialized data.  Always use a maximum field with when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: Use symbolic constants instead of magic values (99, 2, 3, 10).

Comment: `strlen(sentence[i])` is odd as `sentence[i]` refers to the i'th letter of your string so you would only need to `strlen()` once and then subtract `i` to the length of what remains.

Comment: `kataTerbanyak` is the maximum number of words in all of your sentences (ok) but then you use that index across each of the sentences.  As you don't initialize `kalimat` this will likely be referencing uninitialized data.

Comment: The implementation of `encrypt()` behaves like it's passed all sentences but you only pass it a word.  As you presumably only encrypt a word at a time you can simplify it to do so (`sentence[i][j][k]` is undefined for `k > 99`, i.e max word size if you were passing in all the sentences).  The next problem is the algorithm itself, you first do `int panjang = strlen(sentence);` which you ignore, then `int panjang = strlen(sentence[i]);` which shadows the other variable but you are asking a string length of a sentence of words which doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: If length of word then `k=k * strlen(sentence[i][j])`, say, word is "hello" then the cipher text is "h\0........" so '\0' is the string terminator from word, and `.` are undefined as you access the array out of bounds.  If with `strlen(sentence[i])` means number of words in sentence then you still end up with undefined data if there is more than 1 word.  If word length is shorter than k then 10 you end also end up with unitialized data.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `main()` with `encrypt(kalimat[i][j][0])` you pass the first letter each word (`char`) to `encrypt()` which expects a string (`char *sentence`).  This will probably segfault. You probably want to pass each word instead.
2. In `encrypt()` you then index `sentence[i][j][k]` but it's a syntax error as `sentence` is a string (`char *`).  My guess is that you want to scramble the letters of a given word.
3. In `encrypt()` the scramble algorithm doesn't make any sense.  You only want to process the first 2 sentences and 3 first words which is ok but if we only pass in a word (not all sentences) then caller has to implement that logic.  My guess that this is debugging logic so ignoring that for now.  This leaves us with:

   ```
       int panjang = strlen(sentence[i]);
        int index = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k+=panjang)
            {
               kalimatBaru[i][j][index] = sentence[i][j][k];
               index++;
            }
        }
   ```

   `strlen(sentence[i])` doesn't make sense, presumably you are trying to either determine (a) number of words in the sentence (that you will have to pass in as a argument if you encrypt each word separately), or perhaps (b) length of the word.  If `panjang != 1` then you run out of input from `sentence` and lose letters, say, `panjang = 2` then lose every 2nd letter of the the first 10 letters and everything after.  For example: "hello_beautiful_world" would be encrypted as "hloba" (without terminating '\0').  This would be a one-way hash, as you cannot decrypt "hloba" back to "hello_beautiful_world".  If `k` ends up being greater than word length then the output will contain uninitialized data (here using '.'): "hello" would be "hlo..".  Finally, `strcpy(sentence, kalimatBaru);` doesn't make sense as `kalimatBaru` isn't a string, and if it was then it's unsafe when it's not `\0' terminated.

Here's working code but you still need to implement the scrambling logic in `encrypt()`.  The `str()` macro, for now, is magic that converts a number into a string.  Otherwise you would need hard-code "%99s" when reading a word to avoid buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 99
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 99
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

void encrypt(char *word) {
    size_t n = strlen(word);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        word[i] = word[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned jumlahKalimat;
    printf("Masukkan jumlah kalimat: ");
    if(scanf("%u", &jumlahKalimat) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char kalimat[jumlahKalimat][MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < jumlahKalimat; i++) {
        printf("Masukkan jumlah kata kalimat ke-%u: ", i + 1);
        unsigned jumlahKata;
        if(scanf("%u", &jumlahKata) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < MAX_WORDS; j++) {
            if(j < jumlahKata)
                if(scanf("%" str(MAX_WORD_LEN) "s", kalimat[i][j]) != 1) {
                    printf("scanf failed\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            else {
                kalimat[i][j][0] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < jumlahKalimat; i++) {
        printf("Kalimat ke-%d (encrypted): ", i + 1);
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < MAX_WORDS; j++) {
            if (kalimat[i][j][0] != '\0') {
                encrypt(kalimat[i][j]);
                printf("%s ", kalimat[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please accept answer by clicking on the check mark next to it if I answered your question.